# Probability for coins

Tags: probability, permutations

If A has n+1 coins and B has n coins then what is the probability that A has more heads than B

Cases I could make:
I. If A gets more heads than B when A and B toss n coins each independent of $(n+1)^{th}$ trial

II. If A and B get equal number if heads when each toss n coins and outcome of $(n+1)^{th}$ trial is head

I'm not able to carry out the calculations

Comment: Small suggestion to change p and q to A and B. Using p and q is a tiny bit distracting (for me anyway!) as it suggests the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After $n$ tosses, by symmetry,
$A$ and $B$ will have equal probability of having **more** heads = $z,\;$say,
then P(tie) $= 1-2z$

With one more toss, $A$ is sure to win if leading, (*Case I*) and win with $Pr = \frac12$ if tied,  (*Case II*)

thus P(A wins) $= (1\cdot z) +\frac12(1-2z) = \frac12$

Comment: Relating this to the text of the question, the term $p$ in the final equation is from Case I and the term $\frac12(1-2p)$ is from Case II.

Comment: @DavidK: I don't get what you are trying to say. $A$  can't win if losing after $n$ tosses, so there are only two other cases to consider.

Comment: @DavidK: Btw, I have changed the symbol $p$ to $z$ to avoid misconstruing what it stands for.

Comment: I was merely referring back to the text of the question, where the case "$A$ is ahead after $n$ tosses" is Case I and "first $n$ tosses are a tie but $A$ wins toss $n+1$" is Case II. We could enumerate cases where $A$ loses, too, but they were not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks, I have incorporated the case numbers in the answer as an improvement.$\;$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively it should depend on the extra coin that p has and the probability should be $\frac{1}{2}$. Answering based on two cases that you have come up with,

In first case when we ignore $(n+1)^\text{th}$ coin that person p has, p and q have the same probability of throwing more heads owing to symmetry but there is also a probability that they are tied. If $x$ is the probability of p having more heads and $y$ is the probability that they are tied after $2n$ tosses,

$2 x + y  = 1 \implies y = 1 - 2x$

Now the outcome of the $(2n+1)^\text{th}$ toss only affects the probability of p throwing more heads if they are tied after $2n$ tosses (just as a side note - if q was ahead by $1$ head after $2n$ tosses, they can get to a tie after the last toss). If $z$ is the probability of p throwing more heads after the last toss,

$z = x + \frac{y}{2} = x + \frac{1-2x}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Call a coin good if it is head and belong to A or it is tail and belong to B. If A has more head than B then more than half of the $2n+1$ coins are good. The probability is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Doesn't this amount to using the *expectation* after $n$ tosses ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X:$"number of head in $n+1$ trials" and $Y:$"number of head in $n$ trials", then $X\sim\text{Bin}(n+1,0.5)$ and $Y\sim\text{Bin}(n,0.5)$ independent. So, $\mathbf{P}(X>Y)=\mathbf{P}(X+n-Y>n)$ where $n-Y\sim\text{Bin}(n,0.5)$. This implies than $X+n-Y\sim\text{Bin}(2n+1,0.5)$ and then:

$$\mathbf{P}(X>Y)=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}2n+1\\k\end{array}\right)\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{2^{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I don't really understand your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the coins are all independent and fair, you are asking
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X > Y\}
$$
where $X,Y$ are independent with $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n+1,1/2)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,1/2)$.

**Here is an answer without any explicit computation.**

- First, I encourage you to try the cases $n=0$ and $n=1$: they are simple, and give the same answer $1/2$. Based on this, it's natural to think that $1/2$ may *always* be the answer. Let's prove it!
- Write $X = Z+B$, where $Z\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,1/2)$ and $B\sim\operatorname{Bern}(1/2)$ are independent. Then
  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\{X > Y\}
  &= \mathbb{P}\{Z+B > Y\} \\
  &= \mathbb{P}\{Z > Y \mid B=0\}\mathbb{P}\{B=0\} + \mathbb{P}\{Z \geq Y \mid B=1\}\mathbb{P}\{B=1\}\\
  &=\mathbb{P}\{Z > Y\}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{P}\{Z \geq Y \}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
  &=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\mathbb{P}\{Z > Y\}+\mathbb{P}\{Z = Y\}\right)
  \end{align*}$$
  where the third equality uses that $Z,B,Y$ independent and $B$ is $\operatorname{Bern}(1/2)$. Now, by symmetry (since $Z,Y$ are i.i.d.)
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{Z > Y\} = \mathbb{P}\{Z < Y\} = \frac{1-\mathbb{P}\{Z = Y\}}{2}
  $$
  and so
  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\{X > Y\}
  &=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\mathbb{P}\{Z > Y\}+\mathbb{P}\{Z = Y\}\right)
  =\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}
  \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the probability of the outcome of head and tail are equal, we can ignore it. Let $a$ be the number of heads A has and $b$ be the number of heads B has. The set of all possible pairs $(a,b)$ is $$S = \{(a,b) | 0 \leq a \leq n +1, 0\leq b \leq n, a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$
Note that $S$ has $(n + 1)(n + 2)$ elements.

Now we only need to count when A has more heads then B, that is the number of element in the following subset T of $S,$ $$ T = \{(a,b\} \in S | a > b\}.$$
We can count the number of element of $T$ by considering a particular $a = 0,1,2,3,...,n + 1$ and get all $b$ possible. (Or other counting method you know)

Note that the element of $T$ is exactly $$ 1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + (n + 1) = \frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n + 2).$$
Hence the probability of $T$ is $\frac{|T|}{|S|} =\frac{1}{2}$.